# How does someone go to the bathroom on a Puddle Jumper?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

Unlike the shuttles of "Star Trek", which are warp-capable, the Puddle Jumpers of "Stargate: Atlantis" require a gate for interstellar travel. There are numerous episodes where someone - typically 4-6 people at a time - have to spend hours or days aboard a Puddle Jumper to reach their destination.

Given that a Puddle Jumper is only two small rooms (four seats in the front and two benches in the back), and that the entire craft is only a little larger than a [Stryker APC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stryker), it leaves the question of where - or how - going to the bathroom works. I was wondering if this situation was ever addressed in the franchise or extended universe.

**How does someone go the bathroom while in a Puddle Jumper for hours or days?**

As far as I know, we never see bedpans or bags specified for that purpose, although granted there is a lot of stuff stored in the upper compartments of the rear area.

Comment: I'm sure there's a meta layer to this question, an experiment to see who will make the joke...

Comment: Hours a day? Season 4's [Midway](http://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s4/417.shtml) had four people stuck in a Puddle Jumper for a couple of *weeks*! And if McKay is to believed, Sheppard locked himself in the bulkhead after just the first day.

Answer (score 7):

**Specific to the series I do not remember a toilet flush or mention of a character having to relieve themselves in all five seasons and I have watched them multiple times. I do not think this topic was ever covered...**

Not on a toilet... That would be like having a bathroom in a car... you should have taken a bus or a motor home (i.e. the Daedulus). In reality however, US Military forces use what we call a "wag bag" in the field/ during an operation. Basically you have a makeshift plastic toilet that you put a plastic bag into and [...]. Then after you have [...] you tie up the bag and save it to throw away later. I would expect the Atlantis crew to do a similar thing when they left the city.

Fun Fact: APCs don't have toilets either!

Comment: Could you tone down the inter-service rivalry a bit? It's hard to tell what parts of this answer are serious and which parts are a joke.

Comment: I agree, the answer should stick to the point at hand.